# What exceptions does DBI throw?

Tags: perl, dbi

If I set `RaiseError = 1`, what exception is raised when connecting or executing?

If I were to surround my `execute()` method in `try` `catch`, what `exception` should I be catching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Perl Error.pm module, which provides `try` and `catch`, is deprecated.](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Error-0.17020/lib/Error.pm#WARNING) Exceptions, inasmuch as they exist in Perl, are untyped, and here's how you catch one:

```
eval {
  do_something_which_may_throw_exception();
};
if ($@) {
  print "Exception: $@\n";
};
```

In short, the `eval { ... }` block acts as a "try", and the `if ($@) { ... }` acts as a "catch", wherein the exception text is contained in the special variable `$@`.

Comment: Nitpick: `eval` returns the value of the last statement or `undef` on error. If you want to rely on the return value for purposes of error handling, you should return an explicit true value: `eval { do something; 1 } or do { handle_error() }`. I think it is better to do an `if ($@) { handle_error() }`.

Comment: @amon Excellent point; I've updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: What is the first sentence aimed at? There are at least 5 modules that provide try/catch, and Takkun didn't say which one is used.

Comment: Try::Tiny also provides try catch, and isn't deprecated.

Comment: @anon, `if ($@) { handle_error() }` could fail to notice an exception occurred until recently. (5.12? 5.14? 5.16?)

Comment: I wasn't aware of Try::Tiny, or would have recommended it; the only module providing try/catch with which I'm really familiar is Error.pm. I also haven't encountered a case where `if ($@) {...}` failed to catch an exception, but I'm glad to know they exist, and will evaluate Try::Tiny (and probably adopt it) at earliest opportunity. Thanks for the additional clue! It'll come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

The [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#RaiseError) lists and explains a lot of options, many of which relate to error handling.

Perl has two major error handling idioms:

1. Returning a false value. The reason for the error is in some global variable.
2. `die` with some error message (fatal).

By default, DBI uses the first idiom. The error reason is in `$DBI::errstr`. For this to work, you have to check the return values of each and every call to the DBI API.

When you feel lazy, you can use exceptions. Setting `RaiseError` in the handle constructor will make DBI methods throw an exception. From the docs:

> #### RaiseError
>
> Type: boolean, inherited
>
> The `RaiseError` attribute can be used to force errors to raise exceptions rather than simply return error codes in the normal way. It is "off" by default. When set "on", any method which results in an error will cause the DBI to effectively do a `die("$class $method failed: $DBI::errstr")`, where `$class` is the driver class and `$method` is the name of the method that failed. E.g.,
>
> ```
> DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ... error text here ...
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Typically `RaiseError` is used in conjunction with `eval { ... }` to catch the exception that's been thrown and followed by an `if ($@) { ... }` block to handle the caught exception. For example:
>
> ```
> eval {
>   ...
>   $sth->execute();
>   ...
> };
> if ($@) {
>   # $sth->err and $DBI::err will be true if error was from DBI
>   warn $@; # print the error
>   ... # do whatever you need to deal with the error
> }
> ```
>
> In that eval block the `$DBI::lasth` variable can be useful for diagnosis and reporting if you can't be sure which handle triggered the error.

As you can see, exceptions in Perl aren't handled with try/catch, but with `eval { ... }`. After an `eval` that `die`s, the `$@` error variable will be set to that error, and you are free to handle it. Note that DBI does not use exception objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to get back formal exception objects from DBI, you can use the `HandleError` attribute and [Exception::Class::DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/Exception%3a%3aClass%3a%3aDBI). I use it myself. From the Synopsis:

```
use DBI;
use Exception::Class::DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, {
    PrintError  => 0,
    RaiseError  => 0,
    HandleError => Exception::Class::DBI->handler,
});

eval { $dbh->do($sql) };

if (my $ex = $@) {
    print STDERR "DBI Exception:\n";
    print STDERR "  Exception Type: ", ref $ex, "\n";
    print STDERR "  Error:          ", $ex->error, "\n";
    print STDERR "  Err:            ", $ex->err, "\n";
    print STDERR "  Errstr:         ", $ex->errstr, "\n";
    print STDERR "  State:          ", $ex->state, "\n";
    print STDERR "  Return Value:   ", ($ex->retval || 'undef'), "\n";
}
```